# How can I activate, previously deactivated constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, wwdc

I keep references to my `NSLayoutConstraint`

```
var flag = true
@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then for some `@IBAction` I activate/deactivate depending on my `flag` variable:

```
@IBAction func tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    flag = !flag
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
        if self.flag {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([self. myConstraint])
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([self. myConstraint])
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call my action once again, I have an error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` for `myConstrain`.

More over it doesn't animate. What am I doing wrong?

I follow tutorial from WWDC 2015:

[image]

Comment: keep a strong reference of object in IBOutlet declaration. `@IBOutlet strong var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

Comment: Gandalf's comment is correct. deactivating a constraint must cause the view hierarchy to release it's ownership of it. if you don't keep a strong reference, it will be deallocated. @Gandalf, you should make this an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Deactivating a constraint is same as calling `removeConstraint:` for a view. Refer the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/active). So when you remove an object which has `weak` reference will cause the object deallocation for it. Now this object is `nil` and activating it won't have any effect at all. To solve the issue you need to have a strong reference to constraint object.

```
@IBOutlet strong var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Comment: Why there is no animation when I change this?

Comment: Oh, I know, I should add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: IDE gives error if you try to make a weak IBOutlet strong.

Comment: I've used IB in Xcode 8.3.3 to define a strong outlet in the ViewController and the IDE just removes the weak attribute (does not add the strong attribute). So the above code should be written as `@IBOutlet var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!` for it to be a strong reference. And I can confirm it seems to work.